# L1 and L2 cache are managed by operating system?

Tags: operating-system

i know that L1 and L2 cache memories are placed in between Processor and main memory. 
Does Operating system decide when to move the data from main memory to L2 and then L1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the L1, L2, (and L3 if the processor has it) are managed only by the processor.  The operation of the processor cache is completely transparent to the OS.